# My dropdown menu is not showing up

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a dropdown menu in HTML and CSS and it does not work as I'm expecting it to. I don't know what is wrong with it.

I'm attempting to make the menu show the subset of items in the parent items `<ul>` tags on hover and it is not working. Either the child items don't show at all (just the parent items show) or the child items are strewn all across the page in a weird fashion.

My HTML, CSS AND JavaScript code:

[What I'm trying to create](https://media.giphy.com/media/l49JWLEHbQ71K1lWE/giphy.gif) (NOT MY VIDEO).

```js
function copyText(element) {
    var $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
    try {
        document.execCommand("copy");
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    $temp.remove();
}

function copyMessage() {
    console.log("Triggered change");
    $("#note").fadeIn("fast");
    $("#note").fadeOut("slow");
}
```

```css
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700,900');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    max-width: 100% height: auto;
}

.container {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Typography
========*/

.title {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: #b21acs;
}

.title span {
    font-size: 3.75rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: block;
}

.title span2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: block
}

.title span3 {
    display: none;
}

.note {
    display: none;
    color: #b21acd;
}

/*button 
======== */

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.15rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: .5em 1.75em;
    border-color: #b21acd;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: transparent;
}

/*Header
======== */

header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 0em;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li ul {
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 86px;
    line-height: 86px;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav ul li ul li {
    display: none; 
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    opacity: .8;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;     
}

nav ul li ul li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1em;
}

nav a {
    font-weight: 900;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: .8rem;
    padding: .5em;
    color: #FFF;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:focus {
    color: #b21acd;
}

nav ul li ul:hover nav ul li ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav .current {
    color: #b21acd;
}

/* home-hero
======= */

.home-hero {
    background-image: url(../assets/home-hero_background.png);
    padding: 10em 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}

/* Footer
========= */

footer {
    background-color: #b21acd;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>TrigonMC | Home</title>
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="shortcut-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/copyAndChange.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <img src="assets/logo_transparent.png" alt="TrigonMC Network Logo" class="logo">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="current" href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./forums">Forums</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="./bans">Punishments</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Warnings</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Mutes</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Kicks</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bans</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Temp-Mutes</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Temp-Bans</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">IP-Bans</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Apply</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Apply For Staff</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Apply For Builder</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Videos</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">ExZiByte's Livestream</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">GameWolf's Livestream</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Placeholder 1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section class="home-hero">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="title">TrigonMC Network
                    <span>We Support</span>
                    <span2>Versions 1.8 - 1.12.2</span2>
                    <span3 id='ip'>play.trigonmc.com</span3>
                </h1>
                <button id='ipButton' class="button button-accent" onclick="copyText('#ip'); copyMessage();">Copy the IP of the server!</button>
                <div class="note">
                    <p>Copied!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="home-servers">
            <div class="home-servers-textbox">
                <h1>Servers we have</h1>
                <h3>Creative</h3>
                <h5>Coming Soon</h5>
                <h3>Prison</h3>
                <h5>Coming Soon</h5>
                <h3>Skyblock</h3>
                <h5>Coming Soon</h5>
                <h3>Survival</h3>
                <h5>Coming Soon</h5>
                <h3></h3>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <p>TrigonMC Gaming Group Copyright © 2018</p>
            <p>All images Copyright © of respectful owners</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't you want to use bootstrap? it's easy and faster to make this work...
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#nav
after this all you need is to add some custom classes and style it as you want...
I tried to help adjusting your code, but it was confusing because most part of the elements doesn't have a class or an Id...

Comment: Are you willing to walk me through every step as to how to get bootstrap to work? @CalvinNunes

Comment: it's not hard, all you need is to add those links to call it (like you did with jQuery):
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>`

AND

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"</script>`
Now it's working, just copy the code from the first link I send and try it adding your menu options

Comment: "Doesn't work" is completely useless as a description of a problem and the question should be clear without any external resources.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with your css

```
nav ul li ul:hover nav ul li ul li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Basically your layout is something like this:

```
nav -> ul -> li -> ul -> li...
```

What you are telling the browser is something like this:

```
nav -> ul -> li -> ul -> nav -> ul -> li -> ul -> li...
```

Which certainly do not match. Hence, the submenu remains hidden.

So, what to do. Just replace that bit of rule with this

```
nav ul li:hover ul li{
  display: block;
}
```

Also, change the color of link text to something that would not blend in with the background

```
nav ul li ul li a{
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff
}
```

Try to write your stylesheets around classes. It will help you a lot in avoiding such issues in the future.

```js
function copyText(element){
    var $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
    try{
        document.execCommand("copy");
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    $temp.remove();
}
function copyMessage(){
    console.log("Triggered change");
    $("#note").fadeIn("fast");
    $("#note").fadeOut("slow");
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700,900');

 * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 body {
     margin: 0;
     font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
     text-align: center;
 }

 img {
     max-width: 100% height: auto;
 }

 .container {
     width: 95%;
     margin: 0 auto;
 }

 /* Typography
========*/

 .title {
     font-size: 2.5rem;
     color: #b21acs;
 }

 .title span {
     font-size: 3.75rem;
     font-weight: 300;
     display: block;
 }

 .title span2 {
     font-size: 2rem;
     font-weight: 300;
     display: block
 }

 .title span3 {
     display: none;
 }

 .note {
     display: none;
     color: #b21acd;
 }

 /*button 
======== */

 .button {
     display: inline-block;
     font-size: 1.15rem;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     border-width: 5px;
     border-style: solid;
     padding: .5em 1.75em;
     border-color: #b21acd;
     color: #FFF;
     background-color: transparent;
 }

 /*Header
======== */

 header {
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     margin-top: 0em;
 }

 nav ul {
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     list-style: none;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: transparent;
     display: inline-block;
 }

 nav ul li ul {
     border-bottom: none;
     height: 86px;
     line-height: 86px;
     font-size: 14px;
     
     float: left;
     margin: 0 auto;
 }

 nav ul li ul li {
     display: none;
     padding: 0px;
     margin: 0px;
     opacity: .8;
     list-style: none;
     background-color: black;
     float: left;
     line-height: 40px;
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 12px;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 1; 
     
 }

nav ul li ul li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff
}

 nav ul {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style: none;
 }

 nav li {
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 1em;
 }

 nav a {
     font-weight: 900;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-size: .8rem;
     padding: .5em;
     color: #FFF;
 }

 nav a:hover,
 nav a:focus {
     color: #b21acd;
 }

nav ul li:hover ul li{
    display: block;
}
 nav .current {
     color: #b21acd;
 }

 /* home-hero
======= */

 .home-hero {
     background-image: url(../assets/home-hero_background.png);
     padding: 10em 0;
     font-weight: 700;
     background-color: #000;
     color: #FFF;
 }

 /* Footer
========= */

 footer {
     background-color: #b21acd;
     color: #FFF;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>TrigonMC | Home</title>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="shortcut-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/copyAndChange.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <img src="assets/logo_transparent.png" alt="TrigonMC Network Logo" class="logo">
        <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="current" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="./forums">Forums</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                </ul>
            </i>
            <li><a href="./bans">Punishments</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Warnings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Mutes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kicks</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bans</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Temp-Mutes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Temp-Bans</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">IP-Bans</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Apply</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Apply For Staff</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Apply For Builder</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Videos</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">ExZiByte's Livestream</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GameWolf's Livestream</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Placeholder 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>

    <section class="home-hero">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="title">TrigonMC Network
                <span>We Support</span>
                <span2>Versions 1.8 - 1.12.2</span2>
                <span3 id='ip'>play.trigonmc.com</span3>
            </h1>

            <button id='ipButton' class="button button-accent" onclick="copyText('#ip'); copyMessage();">Copy the IP of the server!</button>
            <div class="note">
                <p>Copied!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="home-servers">
        <div class="home-servers-textbox">
            <h1>Servers we have</h1>
            <h3>Creative</h3>
            <h5>Coming Soon</h5>
            <h3>Prison</h3>
            <h5>Coming Soon</h5>
            <h3>Skyblock</h3>
            <h5>Coming Soon</h5>
            <h3>Survival</h3>
            <h5>Coming Soon</h5>
            <h3></h3>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <p>TrigonMC Gaming Group Copyright © 2018</p>
        <p>All images Copyright © of respectful owners</p>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```